# Desktop app connecting to a remote Amazon RDS mysql instance

Tags: java, mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have a java swing desktop app that needs to connect to a remote mysql instance over jdbc. I was thinking of using Amazon RDS for this and creating a security group with an IP of 0.0.0.0 - effectively allowing all IPs to connect to the mysql instance.

I understand that there are security implications with this approach and we should ideal front a remote database with a web application. The desktop app should access the web application via rest/soap and then get access to the db behind it via services exposed by the web app.

Now that's a lot of work. Since I already have the desktop app connecting to a local DB. I just want to move the DB over onto the cloud so that a user can access the same DB from any other system where the same java swing app is installed.

Could someone help me by listing out the security implications on exposing an Amazon RDS DB out on the internet like this?

Also, more importantly, are there any ways of eliminating these risks? Such as SSH Tunneling for example?

Answer (score 0):

The best method is the SSH Tunneling using the KEY that generates by Amazon. 
You can also open an ip with the mask IP of 23.43.65.0/24 and also create a VPN with your desktop and Amazon.

Comment: You cannot SSH into RDS instances for tunneling. You would have to ssh tunnel into a separate/new EC2 instance that has access to the RDS instance.

Answer (score 0):

I know that when I leave a DB open to the world, which I don't normally do, 24 hours a day, 7 days a week automated process keep trying to login in about 10-15 times per second, all day, every day guessing user names and passwords.

If you go this route, which I don't recommend, better make sure your passwords are very, very hard to guess and if you can rename the built-in accounts to something other than 'admin' or 'administrator' all the better.

Comment: You can use certificates with mysql, but you're still exposing the database server to the world, making it a target for DoS attacks. It would be better to stand up a new ec2 instance and use ssh tunneling (see the -L option) or a VPN server (OpenVPN, vyatta, or a VPN appliance from the AWS marketplace). Even with SSH/VPN access, you would want to allow as small of a network range as needed for you and whoever else is connecting to it.